# Switch tab bar failed programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I want to switch tabbar item 2 but it always goes to item 1. in the log, it says it goes to item 2 as well but it shows item 1. i am using the segue. viewControllers![1]

```
if segue.identifier == Constants.Identifiers.goToWinTabFromSearchMatch {
        let tabBarController = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
        let navController = tabBarController.viewControllers![1] as! UINavigationController
        let controller = navController.topViewController as! WinViewController
    }

 @IBAction func doneToBackToWinTab(_ sender: Any) {
    print("i wana back to the win tab")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.Identifiers.goToWinTabFromSearchMatch, sender: nil)


}
```

Comment: What does the code you posted have to do with the text in your question? Where's your code that attempt to switch tabs in a tab controller?

Comment: viewControllers![1]. it tells the second tab. i update the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too am confused by your code snippet as it merely declares a bunch of constants, you're not performing any action whatsoever here. To change tabs in `UITabViewController`, simply use the `selectedIndex` property (it's a simple `Int`). Set it to a valid value and voilà.

However, you have a host of problems in your `if` block regarding optionals. Force-unwrapping and accessing array fields that may not even exist is just asking for trouble. I highly recommend you do it the right way and unwrap them properly via `if let`.

i.e., your `tabBarController.viewControllers![1] as! UINavigationController` is virtually like placing a can of kerosene next to an open fire - you don't know when but it will eventually blow up.

Comment: selectedIndex fixed this issue

Comment: @olx All of the forced unwraps and forced casts in the OP's code is actually fine. It's for a specific segue which is for a specific kind of controller with a specific structure. It's code that should crash if any of it turns out to be wrong. Because if it's wrong it is a programming error that needs to be fixed before the app is shipped. Obviously there are many cases where the use of `!` is bad but this is not one of them.

Comment: @rmaddy, I respectfully disagree. At minimum, you should check for `nil` before force unwrapping an optional. You may think you're safe but remember that a 3rd party supplies these values here (`UIKit` in this case) so you're getting no assurances of anything. You can't count on getting an array of view controllers from the tab controller, you can't count on it having a value at slot 1 and most importantly, you certainly can't assume that whatever is in that optional array[1] will be a `UINavigationController`. However you look at it, it's bad programming and borderline abuse of the language.